# Minecraft Villager not breeding and villagers not moving

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built [this village Breeder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR9NPbGGqfA) on my server and it was working just fine. They were breeding and generating new villagers. I decided to build an automatic wheat, potato and carrot farm with those villagers, so I moved 6 villagers (2 per farm and 1 brown coat per farm) to the farm area.

On a simple test, the wheat farm was working and I got 30 breads within 20 minutes.

Since the breeder was REALLY full, more than 30 villagers (after the relocation), I decided to kill some of them. I built a water stream underground leading to a block full of lava. I know 100% I dind't killed a single villager with a sword or anything comming from my player.

Now, there is nothing working. The villager breeder is stoped, the farms, everything. The villagers doesn't even move. They are stopped on the same block the whole day (i was checking from time to time). They are in the same position, not breeding, not farming, not planting, nothing. Just standing still.

Any ideas what is going on?

I'm playong on minecraft version 1.10.

You [can see these images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVR7R.jpg) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Your minecraft game is lagging.
Try closing all things other than minecraft, and that may help.
Otherwise, restart your computer.
If that still doesn't work, you have too much going on in that world.